# How to set middleware to kc finder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have set Session after I login

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['ckfinder_auth'] = true;
```

where can I set middleware in this path

```
/templateEditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images&CKEditor=editor1&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en
```

Answer (score 0):

When you work with `Laravel`, it's best to write your own codes based on `Laravel`.

For example, To store data in the session, you will typically use the `put`method or the `session` helper:

```
// Via a request instance...
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');
```

or

```
// Via the global helper...
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

for retrieving an item from the session, you can use `get` :

```
$value = $request->session()->get('key', 'default value');
```

or global `session` helper :

```
$value = session('key', 'default value');
```

To determine if an item is present in the session, you may use the `has` method:

```
if ($request->session()->has('users')) {
//
}
```

I suggest you read the `Laravel` document first ([session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session) , [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware))

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new middleware and add it to the Kernel.php file

- `php artisan make:middleware <middleware_name>`
- Change the `handle($request, Closure $next)` as per your requirements.
- Update the `/App/Http/Kernel.php` file by adding your middleware to `protected $routeMiddleware = []` array

Now you have setup adding middleware. Simple add this middleware to the routes by calling

```
Routes::middleware(['middleware_name'])->get(function(){
   return view('your_view');
});
```

Comment: can i do something like this ? Route::middleware(['auth'])->get(function(){
   return url('/templateEditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images&CKEditor=editor1&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en');
});

Comment: I cant use view because  my kc finder is not in view

Comment: How are you routing to the specified URL? I just used view to show you how it works generally. You can change the Route::get function as per your needs.